# Repeated events using AngularJS broadcast

Tags: angularjs

Can we use below code for emitting repeated events, I mean events after every seconds.

```
.service('MyService', function($rootScope) 
{
    function onSendUpdate() 
    {
        // Call a function named 'someFunction' in controller 'MyController'
        $rootScope.$broadcast('dataUpdatedEvent', 
        {
             data: 'JSON'
        });
    }
});


.controller('MyController', function('MyService', $scope) 
{
    $scope.someFunction = function(data) 
    {
        // Process this event 
    }

    $scope.$on('dataUpdatedEvent', function(event, data) 
    {
        $scope.someFunction(data);
    });
});
```

I have one service which communicates with cloud server and based on the server response I want to send event to active controller, currently I have implemented this by adding callback listener. But will it be optimized to use above code to send events to controller which is listening to it.

Comment: How many controllers can be "active"? That is do you have 2 controllers or 100?

Comment: My question was more how many total controllers do you have?

Comment: @MathieudeLorimier : I have total 12 controllers and out of which 4-5 controllers will be active at a time which will listen for the event sent using broadcast. Also the events will be sent by only service to these multiple controllers. But question is will it be ok to send multiple events/broadcasts (within 1 second 5-10 broadcasts) ?